# Ubuntu for laptop with 6 gig ram 32 bit

Tags: 14.04, laptop

Trying to download Ubuntu for first time.  On the Ubuntu site it does not offer me a version 14.04 with 32 bit and about 2G RAM.

Where do I locate a version suitable for my  32 bit  6G RAM laptop  ?

Thanks

Charles

Comment: It is impossible to have 6GB usable/addressable memory with a 32bit computer. Use the 64bit version.

Comment: What are your specs?

Answer (score 0):

The 32-bit Operating System can not generally address more than 2Gb. What is your laptop model? Do you really have 32bit CPU in there?

The maximum available amount of RAM per process for a 32-bit OS is 2 GB. If you have a 64-bit OS, a 32-bit process can allocate up to 4 GB.

Additionally, the entire OS can only address 4 GB for every process combined, while 64-bit OSes can allocate 8 TB.

UPDATE:
The CPU [Intel Core 2 Duo T6570](http://ark.intel.com/products/42841/Intel-Core2-Duo-Processor-T6570-2M-Cache-2_10-GHz-800-MHz-FSB) is 64bit and it is generally recommended to use 64bit OS.

[image]

Comment: It is a Toshiba Satellite Pro  L500.

Comment: The CPU Intel Core 2 Duo T6570 is 64-bit, are you interested in installing 64bit Ubuntu? It is generally recommended to use 64Bit OS.

Comment: Thanks for that. Did not realise it ws 64.  Will try Ubuntu 64